# Why variable A's value does not change by calling function to change it?

Tags: contract-design, contract-debugging

This contract first asks user to set variable A's value and after that calls function, which should change A's value to zero. But A's value does not change to zero. Why?

```
contract test {
    uint A;

    function set(uint SetA) {
        A = SetA;
        changeA(A);
    }

    function changeA(uint A) private {
        A = 0;
        return;
    }

    function variable() constant returns(uint variable) {
        variable = A;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the argument `A` in the function `changeA` is being set to 0 instead of the global variable `A` that you intend.

To fix this, either change the name of the argument to something else, like

`function changeA (uint setA)`

or just don't take an argument, since you aren't using it.